# Checking if pinned package in requirements.txt is latest or not

Tags: python, pip

Consider you have the following `requirements.txt`:

```
pydantic==1.10.7
mypy==1.2.0
pylint>=2.17.3
```

when installing this requirements, pydantic and mypy will install the versions they are pinned to and pylint will install `2.17.4` instead of `2.17.3` because of the operator.

Now there is a newer version of mypy available (`1.3.0`). How can I programmatically find this out having only the `requirements.txt` and only for pinned packages?.

Things ive tried:

- `pip list --outdated`

  - This is basically what i want but ONLY for the packages in `requirements.txt` not for all packages installed
- Scripting a parser to consume the `requirements.txt` and resolve the version

  - This is just a headache. Digging around in `pip._internals` to find how to parse a requirements file, get the canonical name of the pinned package, resolve the versions, support `--extra-index-url`, supporting private repositories etc is just a lot when I feel like this is something that should be relatively simple to do
- https://github.com/sesh/piprot

  - This basically does what I want but its out of date and has been deprecated in favor of `pip list --outdated`

Expected output from the above `requirements.txt` would be something like:

```
pydantic==1.10.7 Up to date
mypy==1.2.0 Out of date. New version is: 1.3.0
pylint>=2.17.3 Will install version 2.17.4 and is Up to date
```

Although I dont really care about the output, more about HOW I resolve the information.

Comment: This gets you closer by not including dependant packages: `pip list --outdated --not-required` - but you need all pinned (`==`) packages, and only if listed in requirements.txt?

Comment: @Jeppe Correct. only pinned and only in requirements.txt

Comment: Might be possible to list, split and grep.. Otherwise here's an ugly one-liner: `import subprocess; print([l for l in [l.rstrip().split("==")[0] for l in open("requirements.txt", 'r').readlines() if '==' in l] if any(l in p for p in subprocess.check_output(["pip", "list", "--outdated", "--not-required"]).decode().splitlines())])` - outputs [`mypy`]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little hacky solution, but here's what you can do:

1. Create a fresh venv - `python -m venv .`
2. Activate it - `Scripts\activate.bat` (or the equivalent)
3. Install requirements from the file - `pip install -r requirements.txt`
4. Get outdated packages with `pip list --outdated`

It has a somewhat big of a drawback that it needs to actually install all the packages in question.

The another approach might be to use something like [yolk3k](https://github.com/myint/yolk) that is able to query PyPI for versions of packages available on the site.
Since you only care about packages with strict versioning (meaning only ones that have `==` and not `>=`) you could parse them out relatively easily from the file and then query with yolk for which version is the latest and compare accordingly.